# Proof Verification: "Composition" of limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

I actually don't even know whether the following statement is true; I'm using it as a sort of lemma to solve another problem.

Suppose $f$ is a real function defined on an open interval containing $x$ and also  for all $t$ in the domain of $f$, $\lim_{y \to t} f(y)$ exists. Then

$$ \lim_{y \to x} f(y) = L \Longrightarrow  \lim_{t \to x}(\lim_{y \to t} f(y)) = L$$

Is this proof fine? I'm feeling iffy about it.

For every neighbourhood $N_1(L)$ we have a neighbourhood $N_2(x)$ such that the whenever $y \in N_2(x)$ and $x\neq y$, $f(y) \in N_1(L)$.

Now, consider $t$ only such that $t \in N_2(x)$. Note $t\neq x$. $\lim_{y \to t} f(y) = L'$ exists, and so for any neighbourhood $N_4(L')$ we have a corresponding $N_3(t)$; we simply make this $N_3(t)$ small enough so that $N_3(t) \subset N_2(x)$. This implies $N_4(L') \subset N_1(L)$, and so $L' \in N_1(L)$

Thus, we have some neighbourhood $N_2(x)$ such that whenever $t \in N_2(x)$ and $x\neq t$, $\lim_{y \to t} f(y) = L' \in N_1(L)$ for any neighbourhood $N_1(L)$ of $L$, which proves the statement.